# how to invoke fragmentB method in another fragmentA

Tags: android-fragments

I have a fragment_A with tabs, consider tabs as fragment_B and C. And am implementing custom keypad with "Done" key in it. In my main Activity iam calling the listener to press the done button

```
// Used when "Done" button pressed in keyboard
@Override
public void keylisten() {

((Housing) fragmentStack.lastElement()).whenokkeypressed();
}
```

Now i want to call a method from fragment_B which goes into the `whenokkeypressed()` of the fragment_A;

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you should do

- Make `whenonkeypressed()` static and call it from class name of the fragment like `Fragment_A.whenonkeypressed()`
- (optional) instead of using keylisten of done in `mainActivity` you should prefer an anonymous inner class like

  ```
  editText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          whenonkeypressed();
      } });
  ```

Comment: cant use static as there are many variables and methods associated with it, cannot make them all static, the button.addactionlister u mean keyboard button?